# Is there a reference brain sample for the RNA-Seq data in the Developmental Transcriptome tool from the Allen Brain Atlas?

Tags: neuroscience, bioinformatics, rna-sequencing, biostatistics

I am using the [Developmental Transcriptome](https://www.brainspan.org/rnaseq/searches?exact_match=false&search_term=%22nectin-1%22&search_type=gene&page_num=0) tool from the Allen Brain Atlas to determine at what stages of development a specific gene is expressed in the human brain.

[image]

I have read the official [documentation](https://help.brain-map.org/display/devhumanbrain/Documentation) as to how the RNA-Seq data for the Developmental Transcriptome was generated and analysed. In the documentation, it says that they used postmortem human brain specimens from a range of different developmental stages (embryonic, early prenatal, early mid-prenatal, late mid-prenatal, late prenatal, early infancy, late infancy, childhood, adulthood).

The heatmap showing the gene expression levels across the different brain samples was generated from the RNA-Seq data. I know that heatmaps show the gene expression levels in a number of samples (e.g. treatments, disease) relative to a control sample.

However, when showing the gene expression levels across the different brain samples they used, I was wondering if there is a reference brain sample that was used? E.g. they are comparing gene expression in other brain samples relative to the reference brain sample. I have read the documentation and there is nothing mentioned regarding this.

I was wondering if anyone who has used the Developmental Transcriptome tool before knows whether the gene expression levels are compared against a reference brain sample? Any insights are appreciated.